# Javascript two Arrays: first counts, second values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two Arrays they both have the same size and look like this:

`a= [ 1, 2, 3, 2]` and `b = ['this', 'is', 'my', 'good example']`.

Array a[i] defines how often the value of b[i] i want to write to a new Array. For my example the result would be `c = ['this', 'is', 'is', 'my', 'my', 'my', 'good example', 'good example']`.

I tried around with [String.repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat?retiredLocale=de) but i dont know how to get it to an Array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this solution will suit you

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 2];
const b = ['this', 'is', 'my', 'good example'];

const c = a.flatMap((count, i) => Array(count).fill(b[i]));

console.log(c);
```

Comment: Adding links to some relevant documentation (like [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)) would make this answer even more useful.

Comment: and an explanation of why flatMap suits this case and what the code does rather than "try this solution" kind of comment

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a loop inside another loop to achieve that

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 2];
const b = ['this', 'is', 'my', 'good example'];

let array = [];
b.forEach((x, i) => {
  for (let j = 0; j < a[i]; j++) {
    array.push(x);
  }
})

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3],
      b = ['a','b','c']

console.log(
  b.reduce((acc, item, idx) => acc.concat(Array(a[idx]).fill(item)), [])
)

// or the opposite

console.log(
  a.reduce((acc, item, idx) => acc.concat(Array(item).fill(b[idx])), [])
)
```

I agree that `flatMap` is ideal for this task, as answered by @lvjonok

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Array#reduce` method as follows:

```js
const
      a = [ 1, 2, 3, 2],
      b = ['this', 'is', 'my', 'good example'],
      
      c = a.reduce(
          (acc,cur,i) => [ ...acc, ...Array(cur).fill( b[i] ) ], []
      );
      
console.log( c );
```